# How do I add a text input to a Samsung Smart TV app?

Tags: javascript, television, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to add a text box to an app for Samsung Smart TV.  I'm following Samsungs [dev guidelines](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/javascript/input_control/tut_js_ime_intro.html) but the following fails because `IMEShell` is undefined.

```
new IMEShell(this._INPUT_ID, this._imeReady.bind(this), "en");
```

I have the following in the index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
```

What script file do I need to include to get access to `IMEShell`?

Comment: I guess you are missing Utils.js

Comment: I can't find a Utils.js in the commonlib folderof the emulator, do you know what the full path is?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so it turns out there are two ways of using input in the Smart TV app depending on which type of project you are using.  If you are creating an [AppFramework](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/apps_framework/appsframework_cover.html) project you need to have `ime` listed as a module in the app.json at the root of the project:

```
{
    "theme" : "base",
    "languages" : ["en"],
    "resolutions": ["540p", "720p", "1080p"],
    "modules" : ["ime"]
}
```

Then you need to include the AppFramework script in the index.html of your project:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/af/2.0.0/loader.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can create a [javascript project](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/getting_started/coding_js.html) which doesn't use the AppFramewrok code and doesn't require that the project be split into 'scenes'.  In this case there are a large number of scripts that need to be included:

```
  <!-- Common API -->
  <!--  Taken from http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/df3455b529adf7c4?forumID=8c1afcc0709c2097 -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/OpenSrc/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Plugin.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/Util/Include.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/Util/Language.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/Plugin/Define.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/IME/ime2.js"></script>
```

This will create a numeric keypad; to create a QWERTY keyboard add the following script within the body tag.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/IME_XT9/ime.js"></script>
```

There is an example of this on the [Samsung Forum](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/df3455b529adf7c4?forumID=8c1afcc0709c2097).

Once the scripts have been included by one of these methods the rest of the [input control docs](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/javascript/input_control/tut_js_ime_intro.html) should work.

Comment: Does anyone know if this has to be used on the initial `index.html` page only? I can't seem to get it to work.